# Symfony Encore: Karma and *.vue Components

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js, karma-runner, webpack-encore

I am currently preparing a new Symfony application and would like to use Vue as well as TypeScript and Karma for testing. Webpack Encore was very helpful for setting up Vue and TypeScript. `yarn encore dev --watch` etc. works beautifully. My only problem is that I cannot get Karma to play nicely with `*.vue` files. Testing normal `*.ts` files is no problem at all. Maybe someone else has had similar problems and knows what to do about it.

My `webpack.config.js` looks as follows:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Export runtime environment, if Encore is not available
var isProduction = true;
try {
  isProduction = Encore.isProduction();
} catch (e) {
  console.log('No Encore environment found, configuring runtime environment');
  Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(
    'dev-server',
    {
      https: true,
      keepPublicPath: true,
    }
  );
}

Encore
  // directory where all compiled assets will be stored
  .setOutputPath('web/assets/build/')

  // what's the public path to this directory (relative to your project's document root dir)
  .setPublicPath('/web/assets/build')

  // empty the outputPath dir before each build
  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

  // will output as web/build/app.bundle.js
  .addEntry('app.bundle', './src/assets/scripts/app.ts')

  // allow *.ts and *.vue files to be processed
  .enableTypeScriptLoader(options => {
    options.appendTsSuffixTo = [/\.vue$/];
    options.transpileOnly = true;
  })

  // will transpile Vue.js components
  .enableVueLoader(options => {
    options.loaders.ts = 'ts-loader!tslint-loader'
  })

  // enable tslint loader and show linting errors in the console
  // based on the "tslint-loader/vue-loader/ts-loader"-snippet:
  // https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2099#issuecomment-292524819
  .addLoader({
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'tslint-loader',
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    enforce: 'pre',
    options: { typeCheck: true, configFile: './tslint.json' },
  })

  // will output as web/build/app.styles.css
  .addStyleEntry('app.styles', './src/assets/styles/app.scss')

  // allow sass/scss files to be processed
  .enableSassLoader()

  // Autoprefixer and other postcss plugins, see postcss.config.js
  .enablePostCssLoader(options => {
    options.config = {
      path: 'postcss.config.js',
    };
  })

  // Add source maps for dev
  .enableSourceMaps(!isProduction)
;

// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And `karma.conf.js` like this:

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],
    files: [
      'src/assets/scripts/**/*.spec.ts',
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/assets/scripts/**/*.ts': ['webpack'],
    },
    webpack: {
      module: webpackConfig.module,
      resolve: webpackConfig.resolve,
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true,
      stats: 'errors-only',
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity,
  });
};
```

I already spent countless hours reading documentation and fixing this and that. I also created sample projects with the Vue CLI, but I just cannot figure out what is wrong about this setup. The following testfile works beautifully:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { App } from '../../core/App';


describe('App Core', () => {
  let app: App;

  beforeEach(() => {
    app = new App();
  });

  it('should have a public app name', () => {
    expect(app.name).to.be.a('string');
    expect(app.name).to.be.equal('my test app');
  });

  it('should have a public app version', () => {
    expect(app.version).to.be.a('string');
  });

});
```

But here, `HelloWorldComponent` is undefined:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { VueConstructor } from 'vue';
import HelloWorldComponent from '../../../components/vue/HelloWorld.vue';


describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {

  it('should be a valid Vue component', () => {
    expect(HelloWorldComponent).to.be.a(VueConstructor);
  });

});
```

Solutions or ideas are very, very welcome. Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who silently tried to help me :) I found the problem, a plugin was required but not loaded:

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],
    files: [
      'src/assets/scripts/**/*.spec.ts',
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/assets/scripts/**/*.ts': ['webpack'],
    },
    webpack: {
      module: webpackConfig.module,
      resolve: webpackConfig.resolve,
      // This is the relevant bit:
      plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("app.styles.css") 
      ]
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true,
      stats: 'errors-only',
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity,
  });
};
```

Works like a charm now :)